# How to retrieve the current and next element from mysqli_fetch_array() in while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table which can have multiple same records. so I want to do some task if there are multiple records are same. How can I check that in this case.

```
<div>
<table class="table">

<thead class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:#EBF5FB;">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Locations</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Users</th>
    <th>Edited</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<div class="pre-scrollable">
<tbody id="myTable">

 <?php
        include_once 'Connection.php';
        $check_test=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],"select * from test ORDER bY id DESC");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_test)) {
            echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['region'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['number'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['rollno'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['created'].'</td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }   
    ?>
</tbody>
</div>

</table>
</div><br/>
```

Table rows example :

```
'genarate id', 'us-west-4', 'Test', '1', '15', '2018-06-06 23:43:02','93'

'genarate id', 'us-east-3', 'Test', '1', '15', '2018-06-06 23:43:02', '93'
```

If the rows are like this, I need to print the records one time like

```
'genarate id', 'us-east-3 , us-west-4', 'Test', '1', '15', '2018-06-06 23:43:02',  '93'
```

Comment: Save the array result in a cached array as you iterate then use `array_diff` to find duplicates: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Answer (score 0):

Not in php but in sql, you change the query to do this :

```
SELECT name, email, address, rollno, count(*) as nb
FROM test
GROUP BY name, email, address, rollno
ORDER BY id DESC
```

then in php you just need to display the number :

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_test)) {
            echo $row['name'];
            echo $row['email'];
            echo $row['address'];
            echo $row['rollno'];
            echo $row['nb'];
 }
```

Since your comment, what you are looking for is GROUP_CONCAT, here is the query :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names, email, address, rollno
FROM test
GROUP BY email, address, rollno
ORDER BY id DESC
```

As you didn't write on wich field you want to concat, i have chose name but you can do it for any column if you change the group by too.
To learn more about the function group_concat, the manual is there : 
[group concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I need the next values also

Comment: I am printing the current values in looping right, in the same way I need the next row values at a time

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get the distinct records by using SELECT DISTINCT statement.

<?php
    include_once 'Connection.php';
    $check_test=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],"select DISTINCT name, email, address, rollno from test ORDER bY id DESC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_test)) {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['email'];
        echo $row['address'];
        echo $row['rollno'];
    }   
?>
```

Or if you want to know which record are duplicate then -
you can use this sql query

```
SELECT 
  first_name, COUNT(first_name),
  last_name,  COUNT(last_name),
  email,      COUNT(email)
FROM
  contacts
GROUP BY 
  first_name , 
  last_name , 
  email
HAVING  COUNT(first_name) > 1
AND COUNT(last_name) > 1
AND COUNT(email) > 1;
```